# Unable to connect with psql: SSL error: invalid padding

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to a Postgres instance running on Google Cloud Platform using psql.

I got the certificate using:

```
gcloud beta sql ssl server-ca-certs list --instance=[instance-name] --format='value(cert)' > server-ca.pem
```

and then tried connecting using psql to the instance using:

```
psql "host=[ip] port=[port] user=[user] dbname=[db] sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=server-ca.pem"
```

This returns the error: `SSL error: invalid padding`

I have checked the certificate for valid unix endlines, changed the wrapping (making sure the whole certificate fits on one line, etc.)

Any pointers into what might be going wrong here or how to debug this are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new server-ca certificate and rotating it solved the SSL connection issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, just need to restart PostgreSQL to load the new certificate.